# Packaging "visual studio c# windows application"project then setup on client without need to install Netframework

Tags: c#

I finished programming my project with Visual studio 2008 c# windows form application and I created setup project using plug-in (setup wizard) with visual studio 2008.
but when I install my program after packaging with this plug-in there is wrong message appear on the screen:"this install want to install .Netframework 3.5"
what I want..?
I want packaging my project to instal on client computer without need to install .Netframework
liprary.How I can do it using any program anyway...please give me express steps

I not mean:I never want to install .Netframework 3.5  but I want to know waht is the way to summary wahat the liprary in using with my project then include this liprary in my project package, becasue I want to small my setup file size.

sorry because my question wasn't purposely.

Thank you all..

Comment: In short, you can't.  You need to install the .NET framework to run a C# program.  If that's a problem, you'll probably need to use another language that doesn't require a framework installation.

Comment: .NET applications require .NET. Simple.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Just because it can't be done doesn't mean it wasn't a legitimate (albeit newbie) question. In fact, I think it led to a good suggestion by @davecenter2002 to use a web app.

Comment: @BobHorn Probably because it's so frequently asked; the information is rather readily accessible; it's clear little research effort was done by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute a .Net program on a client computer, you automatically need the .Net Framework to be installed.

What you can do is to use [clickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965.aspx#clickonce) to have the client computers to automatically download and install the .Net Framework for you.

Answer (score 2):

With the recent advent of vNext, this concern is starting to recede into the distance.

[.NET CORE 5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cesardelatorre/archive/2014/11/18/what-is-net-core-5-and-asp-net-5-within-net-2015-preview.aspx) is bridging the gap in terms of deployable applications across OS and architecture lines.  [Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-5) highlighted the fact that since the dependencies are deployed with the application:

> You can deploy the .NET Core runtime with your app which means your
>   app will run with this deployed version of the runtime rather than the
>   version of the runtime that is installed on the host operating system.

While this does not yet affect desktop applications as of May 2015, it is a large step forward and may end up getting carried over to desktop applications as well.

---

While this does not help your immediate predicament, if you want to remain free of frameworks for your target audience, consider creating a web project for your next piece of software.  While you'll need an IIS server to host the application (there are lots of companies that do that), your viewers will only need a browser.